# How to inject JAR version when running Gradle?

Tags: gradle, versioning

Typically I see `version` statically defined inside a `build.gradle` or `gradle.properties` file like so:

```
version = '1.5.3'
```

But I would like to "inject" the version dynamically when I run `gradle jar`, so something like this:

```
gradle jar --version "1.5.4"
```

etc. But it doesn't look like Gradle supports this. In any event, I need a way to define the version number **outside** of the buildscript or any of its property files. Any way to accomplish this is a viable solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version is just a property of the project, that you can define externally, as any other property, using the -P option:

```
gradle jar -Pversion=1.5.4
```